# Need help understanding how std::promise and std::future work in this case

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

void listenForInput(std::promise<bool>&& interruptPromise)
{
    std::cin.get();
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    interruptPromise.set_value(true);
    std::cout << "[Speech 100] no u \n";
}

bool is_ready(std::future<bool> const& f)
{ 
    return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    std::promise<bool> interruptPromise;
    //interuptPromise.set_value(false); 
    /* Commenting line above makes program work. Uncommenting results in while
       loop below not being executed */
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    
    std::future<bool> interruptFuture = interuptPromise.get_future();
    
    std::thread reply(listenForInput, std::move(interruptPromise));
    
    while (!is_ready(interruptFuture))
    {
        std::cout << "Your mother was a hamster, "
                     "and your father smelt of elderberries "
                     "(Press any key to reply)\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(2) );
    }
    
    reply.join();
    
    std::cin.get();
    
    return 0;
}
```

## Context

In the code above in the main thread the same line of text is constantly being displayed until it's interrupted from the other thread. The interrupt occurs after any input from the user. The message of user making an input is being delivered to the main thread via `std::promise` and `std::future`. `is_ready` is an utilitarian function used for checking whether promise was satisfied.

My interest lays in the third line of the `main()` function and what's around it. At first I tried to set value of `interruptPromise` in advance to false (which would indicate that interrupt didn't occur so that later in other thread I'd change it to true to indicate that it did occur). It resulted in `interruptPromise` being satisfied before `while` loop even started thus the loop not being executed.

## Questions

1. I get that `std::promise` becomes satisfied when `set_value` is called. But how do I assign a value in advance and then make `std::future` react to it being changed (for instance `future` would react to `false` `bool` being changed to `true`)?
2. Would I ever need to do such a thing?
3. Does `std::promise` has default values for certain types (if it needs such at all)?

Comment: From [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) "_Note that the `std::promise` object is meant to be used only once._"

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with your program though it sounds like you need a queue instead of a promise.. BTW, you don't need any `atomic_thread_fence` in this example, the `promise` already takes care of memory ordering (that is also explained in documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primise/future isn't a value that changes, it is a value that is delivered later.

If you want a value that changes, you can stich together one out of a mutex, condition variable and a bool.  However, reasoning about a bool that changes more than once in a multithreaded environment will break most people's brains in my experience.

Better options are things like queues of data guarded by the above, and try pop or try pop all methods that get data off the queue if it is there.

```
template<class T>
struct threadsafe_queue{
  std::optional<T> try_pop();
  std::optional<T> wait_and_pop();
  bool is_aborted() const;
  std::deque<T> pop_all();
  void push(T);
  void abort();
  
private:
  std::condition_variable cv;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::deque<T> queue;
  bool isAborted=false;

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() const;
};
```

write the above, then send the user input via the queue.  The main thread does a try pop and processes if it gets any.

```
std::optional<T> try_pop(){
  auto l=lock();
  if (is_aborted()||queue.empty()) return {};
  auto r=queue.front();
  queue.pop_front();
  return r;
}
std::optional<T> wait_and_pop(){
  auto l=lock();
  cv.wait(l, [&]{return is_aborted()||!queue.empty();});
  if (is_aborted()) return {};
  auto r=queue.front();
  queue.pop_front();
  return r;
}
void push(T t){
  auto l=lock();
  if (is_aborted()) return;
  queue.push_back(std::move(t));
  cv.notify_one();
}
void abort(){
  auto l=lock();
  isAborted=true;
  cv.notify_all();
}
```

there are some sample implementations.